# overflow hidden in opera

Tags: css, opera

overflow hidden does not work for Opera. Image is at the top of the circle. Any idea how to fix this?

```
<div class='circular'> <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Yt8Baaeww9k/Uas6HjPMMrI/AAAAAAAACuY/k4Wz0pErtCA/s1600/1opera9.jpg" /> </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.circular {
overflow:hidden;

width: 48px;
height: 48px;


border-radius: 550px;


box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 10, 2.8);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 10, 0, 2.8);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 10, 0, 2.8);


background-color:lightgrey;

}
```

this is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LfhH9/

Comment: Works for me. 19.0.1326.63

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Too bad the majority of Opera users are still on Opera 12.1.  Versions 15+ may as well not exist.

Comment: I use opera 12.16 build 12.16. Says it is last updated. But not working

Comment: The old Opera (using Presto engine won't get any more updates, it's dropped), the new opera is Opera Next (using the webkit engine)

Comment: Note, that while the latest Opera’s do use Blink (not WebKit), users are not auto-updated from Opera 12.1. As such Opera 12.1 is still the most popular version of Opera by most stat sources. Opera Mini may never update to Blink, and it has a lot more users than Opera Desktop. A number of TV browsers are also still based on Presto.

Answer (score 0):

Presto-based Opera has had a long standing issue with clipping images when its parent has `border-radius` applied.

There are two possible solutions, neither of which may work for you, depending on your circumstances.

You could apply the image using `background-image` instead of an `img` element. This works as expected in Opera.

Another solution is to apply the border-radius to the `img` element instead of the `div`. This will also fix the problem with the clipping, but will not work if you need a wrapper element for other reasons. I switched the selector to apply to the img in this quick [demo update](http://jsfiddle.net/LfhH9/1/) just to show the clipping working.

As an aside, you should also move the unprefixed `box-shadow` after the prefixed version, so that the unprefixed version is the one that applies in browser that support both prefixed and unprefixed. It is always best to use the latest implementation where possible.